# Finding a basis for the column space. Confusing text

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading these two passages in my text:

[image]

[image]

I don't get where the leading 1st are in B. When looking at the leading 1, is the author looking at the row with the leading 1 or the column with the leading 1? What does this leading 1 tell us? More importantly, how are they linearly independent?

Is the idea behind determining linear independence here simply just that the leading 1 is actually a sort of columnar leading 1 (the one is at the bottom of the column) and it's clear since there are only 0s in the row of the leading 1, that the first, second, and 4th columns are linearly independent?

Comment: You might want to have a look through [Jwan622's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/77211/jwan622) series of questions. You’re working from the same text and appear to be confused by many of the same things.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is what space you're looking at. The second example is to find a basis for the column space. This is done by first finding the pivot columns of A. That is done by row reducing and finding the columns that have the leading entries. The basis is found by taking **the columns of A that correspond to those pivot columns**. Be careful! The basis IS NOT the pivot columns themselves because the row operations changes the columns.

For the row space (the first example), when you row reduce, the basis IS the non-zero **rows** of the ecehlon form.

Comment: I realize this, but why does this work? So you find the leading 1s (in the row right ,not the column?) and then take the columns corresponding to the row reduced matrix in the original matrix as linearly independent... but why?